Dependencies errors in one jupyter notebook but not another (same environment)
I have two notebooks for different projects and I am trying to import the same dependencies but one notebook comes up with an error, the other one runs perfectly fine.
I'm not sure why it's happening, any insight would be greatly appreciated!
TIA
snip of the error
I tried running the same code as my other notebook, on the same environment, that did run properly.
